# Update cell where ID

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this form:

```
<?php
  $id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<form method="POST" action="send.php?<?php echo $id; ?>"
<p><input type="text" class="result" size="80%" required placeholder="number">
</p>
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="id">

<div style="width:200px;">
<span class="a-button a-button-primary a-padding-none  a-button-span12">
  <span class="a-button-inner">
    <input id="continue-top" class="a-button-text " tabindex="0" type="submit" value="Continue" >
  </span>
</span>
  </div>
</p>
</form>
```

I want to update column `result` where

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

How I can update 'result' where id= an example 26  here?:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `cc` SET `result`=
                         ('".$_POST['result']."')",$db)  ;
header( 'Refresh: 1; url=admin.php' );
```

Comment: Some element needs the name `result`. This opens you to SQL injections. `send.php?<?php echo $id;?>` also doesn't set a GET parameter. You need `id=`.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET['id']; 
?>
<form method="POST" action="send.php">
    <p><input type="text" class="result" name="result" size="80%" required placeholder="number"></p>
    <p>
        <div style="width:200px;">
            <span class="a-button a-button-primary a-padding-none  a-button-span12">
                <span class="a-button-inner">
                    <input id="continue-top" class="a-button-text " tabindex="0" type="submit" value="Continue" >
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
</form>
```

And on send.php get this ID and RESULT with `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['result']` and protect with `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Like that:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$result = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['result']);
```

To update db table `cc` do this with:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `cc` SET `result` = ' " . $result . " ' WHERE `id` = ' " . $id . " '", $db);
```

Comment: You forgot a closing ">" at the beginning of your form

Comment: i saw, that when  construction with " " stay near the WHERE, WHERE doesnt work.

Comment: You do know that `$variables` get automatically expanded when inside a double quoted string literal dont you. so this would be easier to read and much easier to debug `mysql_query("UPDATE \`cc\` SET \`result\` = '$result'  WHERE \`id\` = '$id' ", $db);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE cc SET result='Doe' WHERE id=26";
```

But here should be someting like this, if you want $_GET[id] to work:

```
<form method="POST" action="send.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"
```

Do not forget to sanitize data avoiding mysql injection:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Comment: I remake code, but again, doesnt work. Whats wrong?

`<?php
include('connect.php');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cc` WHERE `id`='$id' ",$db);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
mysql_query("UPDATE `cc` SET `result` = ' ".$_POST['result']." ' WHERE `id` = ' " . $_POST['id'] . " '", $db);
header( 'Refresh: 1; url=admin.php' );

?>
`

Answer (score 0):

Put value in input type hidden. Which id record you want to update for example

Replace this code.

```
<form method="POST" action="send.php?<?php echo $id; ?>"
<p><input type="text" class="result" size="80%" required    placeholder="number">
</p>
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value='26'>

<div style="width:200px;">
<span class="a-button a-button-primary a-padding-none  a-button-span12">
<span class="a-button-inner">
<input id="continue-top" class="a-button-text " tabindex="0" type="submit" value="Continue" >
</span>
</span>
</div>
</p> 
</form>
```